# Applying central limit theorem to moment generating function

Tags: probability, statistics, central-limit-theorem

A random variable X has moment generating function $e^{500t+500t^{2}}$ .

Find P(27100 < $(X − 500)^2$ < 50200).

I'm a little confused how exactly I can apply a moment generating function, to which I don't know the distribution, to a central limit-type problem where I want to find the probability that it lies between two quantities. How do I start this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The normal distribution with mean  $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ has mgf
$$\exp\left(\mu t+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 t^2\right).$$
So from your given mgf you  can see that $X$ has normal distribution, and can identify the mean and variance of $X$.  The rest of the calculation is probably familiar.

Comment: So I get that U is normally distributed with mean 500 and variance 5000, but how can I use that and "subtract" from 500 in the middle of the expression?

Comment: If the mgf is really $500t+500t^2$ then the variance is $1000$. We want the probability that $\sqrt{27100}\lt |X-500|\lt \sqrt{50200}$. Draw the normal curve. We want twice (can you see why?) the probability that $\sqrt{27100}\lt X-500\lt \sqrt{50200}$. This is a routine calculation, we want twice the probability that $\sqrt{27100}/\sigma\lt Z\lt \sqrt{50200}/\sigma$.

Comment: Ah, I got it. I guess I was a little confused about the whole "point" of turning X - 500 to Z . We want twice the probability because of the absolute value, no?

Comment: $\frac{X-500}{\sigma}$, where $\sigma^2=1000$, has standard normal distribution, since $X$ has mean $500$. Note by the way that the Central Limit Theorem is not involved, we are not *approximating* using a normal, $X$ is actually just plain normal.

Comment: And yes, it is because of the absolute value. There are two regions where our inequalities hold, but because of the symmetry we need not do two separate calculations.